# Why can't I Remove WhiteSpaces in Java?

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I'm desperately trying to remove white spaces from a String (that late i want to be able to convert into an int) but i can't seem to get it all right.

```
String input;
if(GamePlay.GameStart == true){
    input = Terminal.askString("Welcome to MASTERMIND! \n Please Give in Your Game Attributes \n");
            input.replaceAll("\\s","");
}else
    input = Terminal.askString(""); 
if (input.equals("Quit") || input.equals("quit")){
    Quit();

}
else if(GamePlay.GameStart == true){

    System.out.println(input); .......(code follows)
```

Can you please tell me,what it is that i'm doing wrong?
PS:I've tried \W" and \S" too

Comment: The String class is immutable - it will never change the content, but always return a new instance of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace

```
input.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

with

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

It will work, because strings are immutable, so `replaceAll()` won't change your string object, it will return a new one. So you assign your variable `input` to the string returned by `input.replaceAll("\\s","");`

Also, you should try to follow the Java naming conventions, and have your fields and variables start with a lowercase letters.

And, you can also replace

```
if(GamePlay.GameStart == true) {
```

with

```
if(GamePlay.GameStart) {
```

because in your version you compare the value of `GamePlay.GameStart` with `true`, and only execute the `if` block if that evaluation is `true`, whereas in my version, the `ìf` block is executed if `GamePlay.GameStart` is `true` (although the compiler probably optimizes it away anyway).

On another note, you can also replace

```
if (input.equals("Quit") || input.equals("quit")){
```

with

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
```

because, well I think it's obvious.

Comment: That was probably the best Answer i ever got from somebody online.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable. You need to assign your result of the newly created `String` returned by `replaceAll`:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.replaceAll("\\s","");` returns a string with the spaces removed. But if you don't keep a reference to it you won't be able to see the result. You probably meant:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a very common mistake for beginners.

As others have mentioned, you need to know that [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns a new string and doesn't change the current one, since strings are immutable in Java.

So use:

```
input=input.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

If you wish, you can have assistant plugins to help you with such bugs, such as [**findBugs**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/findbugs-eclipse-plugin) and [**codePro**](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro).