# java- trying to replace "&" with "&amp;" but still seeing unchanged text

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I Remove WhiteSpaces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539791/why-cant-i-remove-whitespaces-in-java)

In a java program, to make some XML parseable without giving errors, I am substituting the `"&"` character with `"&amp;"` using the following code-- the variable 'origString' is storing each line in the input file (one by one)

```
 if(origString.contains("&"))
 {  

      System.out.println(" This line contains & --");

      System.out.println(" origstring=" + origString);

      origString.replace("&" , "&amp;");

      System.out.println(" origstring after replacing '&' =" + origString);
 }
```

However, when I run the above code, I am getting the same string value unchanged- i.e. the "&" remains as it is in the origString variable.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I correct this error?

Also, will the same problem apply to replacement of "<" , ">" , """, "'" characters (with equivalent text that is acceptable in XML files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` are immutable so you need to assign it back to `String` variable to actually make changes in that variable
try this:

```
origString = origString.replace("&" , "&amp;");
```

and check in same way if you are doing same thing for **replacement of "<" , ">" , """, "'" characters**

Answer (score 1):

```
origString = origString.replace("&" , "&amp;");
```